Prove that Gaussian elimination solves maximum XOR subset problem?
Given an array of positive integers. Find the subset that maximizes the XOR of all of its elements?  This can be solved by "Gaussian elimination" in the following manner:

Pick the largest integer with highest set bit.
Transform all the integers with the bit in the same position 1 by XOR-ing them with the above chosen integer.
Repeat the process with the transformed array

Algorithm in question:  Maximum XOR subset
The answer to maximum XOR is the result of XOR-ing all transformed elements.
I'm not sure what Gaussian elimination algorithm is trying to solve here. What I think of is:
\begin{cases}
{(a_1^{(1)}v^{(1)} \oplus ... \oplus a_1^{(N)}v^{(N)}) = p_1} \\
.... \\ 
{(a_n^{(1)}v^{(1)} \oplus ... \oplus a_n^{(N)}v^{(N)}) = p_n} \\ 
\end{cases}
where $p$ is the maximum XOR. $a^{1}, ..., a^{N}$ is the elements. $v_1, ..., v_N$ determines what element to choose.
But this has N unknowns with n equations, which is, I think, not what the algorithm is solving(n unknowns, N equations). Is it trying to multiply all $p_i$ to each bit value in each bit position?
Why XOR-ing all transformed elements by column here? What exactly is the equation here?
Thanks :D

Relevant: Subset XOR problem

@PålGD The link is useful, but I can't quite figure out the system of equations. Can you help me with that? :(

The answer to your first question is that it is simply a heuristic for Gauss–Jordan Elimination. Any integer with highest bit set will do.

@PålGD I do notice that. Thanks :D. But I can't figure out the equation the algorithm is solving. I edited the question to address this. Could you guide me more?

Sorry. My linear algebra is just limited :D. The idea is quite interesting. You transform the original set of basis bit vectors into another set of basis bit vectors, which span the same vector space. Gaussian elimination is so clever that it forces the maximization of the linear combination $v^{(1)}x^{(1)} + v^{(2)}x^{(2)} + ... + v^{(t)}x^{(t)}$ happens at $v^{(1)} = v^{(2)} = ... = 1$, where $t$ is the number of bits. That's the reason you XOR everything in the $\boldsymbol{x}$.
